# Assign the `priority` value for current date sorted using MySql 8

Tags: mysql

I need update the column `priority` on the table `dotable` using a database MySql version 8.0.12

I need assign the `priority` value for current date sorted from the old date/time to the last recent date/time.

This is the table `dotable`

```
+---------------------+----------+
| dt                  | priority |
+---------------------+----------+
| 2021-08-10 00:15:26 |   NULL   |
| 2021-08-10 00:32:10 |   NULL   |
| 2021-08-10 00:53:23 |   NULL   |
| 2021-08-10 01:15:38 |   NULL   |
| 2021-08-10 01:30:43 |   NULL   |
| 2021-08-10 01:52:26 |   NULL   |
| 2021-08-10 02:38:00 |   NULL   |
| 2021-08-10 03:31:52 |   NULL   |
| 2021-08-10 09:22:57 |   NULL   |
| 2021-08-10 09:30:57 |   NULL   |
+---------------------+----------+
```

I need this output

```
+---------------------+----------+
| dt                  | priority |
+---------------------+----------+
| 2021-08-10 00:15:26 |       1  |
| 2021-08-10 00:32:10 |       2  |
| 2021-08-10 00:53:23 |       3  |
| 2021-08-10 01:15:38 |       4  |
| 2021-08-10 01:30:43 |       5  |
| 2021-08-10 01:52:26 |       6  |
| 2021-08-10 02:38:00 |       7  |
| 2021-08-10 03:31:52 |       8  |
| 2021-08-10 09:22:57 |       9  |
| 2021-08-10 09:30:57 |       10 |
+---------------------+----------+
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE dotable
JOIN ( SELECT dt, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dt) AS priority
       FROM dotable ) AS enumerated USING (dt)
SET dotable.priority = enumerated.priority;
```

The query assimes that none duplicated `dt` values are present in a table.

If duplicates are present then some third column which allows to distinguish such rows must exist, and id must be added into the query. If duplicates are present and none such third column exists then the task is formally unsolvable.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
SELECT dt, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dt) AS priority
FROM dotable
ORDER BY priority;
```